# declaring javascript array with multiple fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, initialization

So I want to declare a javascript array with multiple fields.

For example I know you can do something like

```
var data = [
{
    "field one": "a",
    "field two": "b",
},
{  
    "field one": "c",
    "field two": "d",
}
]
```

However, I don't know to do create such an array dynamically so that I don't have to initialize the fields at declaration time.

Answer (score 6):

You can add values dynamically to an array using the `push()` method.

```
var data  = [];
....
....
data.push({
    "field one": "a",
    "field two": "b",
})
```

Also if you want to add keys to an existing object dynamically, you can use the `[]` syntax

```
var obj = {};
...
obj['field one'] = 'a';
obj['field two'] = 'b';
data.push(obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

Each individual array element is a [JavaScript Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).  You can create new fields using dot or bracket syntax:

```
var obj = {};
obj.fieldone = "one";
obj["field two"] = "two";
```

In your case you have to use bracket notation because of the space.

You can insert newly created objects into the array using `.push`:

```
data.push(obj);
```

You can then access individual fields:

```
data[0]["field one"] == "a";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = [];

var fields = ["one", "two"];
var length = fields.length;

var char = 97; // a

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var object = {};

    for (var j = 0; j < length; j++) {
        object["field " + fields[j]] = String.fromCharCode(char++);
    }

    data.push(object);
}
```

See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/yqg3D/